# adding to the name of the function some php variable

Tags: php

I have a function called `check_nickname()`
And I want to write something like this

```
$ttt='nickname';
check_.$ttt();
```

How can I do it correct ?

Comment: What do you want the function to actually do? What do you have so far?

Comment: I'll have several functions but will call them with a single line depending on the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable that holds the function name, and apply parentheses to it:

```
$ttt='nickname';
$funcname = 'check_'.$ttt;
$funcname();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would advise against that.

this will produce unmaintainable and undebuggable code.

I'd make one function which does all the verifications.

Comment: I think you are right. Despite the fact that this method will work I'll try to make one for all.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create another variable, such as `$a = "check_".$ttt;`, then call `$a();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ttt = 'nickname';
$your_function = 'check_' . $ttt;

$your_function();
```